# I want to store names in two different languages in my database

Tags: database, laravel-5.8

I'm creating a table where I want to store names in two different language in my Database. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: well then create it. Please ask question with problem, what have you tried / done, and output.
you have'nt asked any question

Comment: What you have tried so far?